# Just starting out on guitar - what to practice?

Tags: guitar

Just a general question for people who have been playing for a little bit: I’m just wondering, when first starting out on guitar, should I practice my chords or try songs too? I find I’m getting frustrated with the question of what to focus on first.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn both. You won't be able to play songs without knowing chords, and just knowing chords without giving them a function will make the memorising process more complicated and less interesting.

When teaching my students, I first teach simple songs so they can learn basic chords (major, minor), then more advanced songs for learning other chords (like C7, Cmaj7, Cm7/9, C/G, etc) and we keep progressing like this. It's also good to balance your learning between repertoire and skills.

In addition, if you get to an intermediate level and then have the opportunity to learn harmonic theory, you can change your strategy for practising chords inside progressions and not specific songs.

Comment: Knowing some songs also keeps a student interested and shows them they're making progress. Just practicing chords and doing exercises without any context can get boring and lead students to feel "they're not getting anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing guitar and many other instruments for a few years now and I would give this advice in the order of guitar learning,
1. Do some coordination exercises and simple songs
2. Find songs with simple chords (open chords) and play them, make sure you play them slowly first and make sure every note is clear when you play.
3. After this start getting into different strumming patterns.
4. Now learn some theory behind the chords and music in general. This will increase your ability to learn barre chords later and construct the chords yourself so you don't have to google them each time.
5. After this get into doing some picking patterns.
6. Learn barre chords.
7. Choose your own path and style of music to continue on (I did Fingerstyle) there are the genres of hard rock, to Spanish, to Fingerstyle to choose from.

Good luck in learning guitar! Also, if you have the ability, try to learn and master hard songs early. One of my guitar teachers had previous music experience and could skip the theory to doing this and it has really benefited his skill.